# Pulling user data from external database

Tags: javascript

I have a game that utilizes mongodb to store the user information. What I am trying to do is use drupal as a community front so users can register for the game in drupal. The problem is that I don't know where to begin since I'd need to pass the user info created in drupal into mongodb so they would be able to log in and play the game.

Is there a way that I can pass the registered user info into mongo so the users can log into the game?

Also I'm running drupal on MySQL.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That is too broad to give any real specifics, but in general:

- create a form (or utilise the user registration form) to register all the relevant information
- override the submit function for that form, and include a call to a php function that will access and append the mongo db. keep in mind that if the db in on a different server, security settings on the server may prevent this from being possible. If this were the case, you would need to send a POST call or similar to a php file on that server (or use an API if available) in order to update the server db.

to get you started on the form:

[Drupal Form API Reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7)

[WebForm](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform)

[Form Builder](https://www.drupal.org/project/form_builder)

Comment: Thanks! That put me on the right track and I will be using a POST call to write form data to external mongodb.